# react.js pass value using link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Here is my `Profile` class :

```
class Profile extends React.Component {
     state={email:'',userName:'',userID:''};
     render() {
              return(
     <div>
     ...
            <Link to={{pathname:"/edit",state:this.props.state}}>
     ...
     </div>

    );
}
}
export default Profile;
```

And here is my `ProfileEdit` class :

```
class ProfileEdit extends React.Component {
state={email:'',userName:'',userID:''};
render() {
    return(
        <div>
        ...
                        <TextField valueOfEmail={this.state.userID}/>
        ...
        </div>
    );
}
}
export default ProfileEdit;
```

And here is my `TextField` class :

```
class TextField extends React.Component {
render() {
    const {valueOfEmail}=this.props;
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="form-label-group">
                <input type="text" id="inputEmail" value={valueOfEmail} className="form-control" placeholder="Name" required autoFocus/>
                <label htmlFor="inputEmail">Enter Name</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}
export default TextField;
```

It gives me error sometimes and sometime it doesn't, but it renders nothing.

Here is the error I have got :

[image: react.js pass state correctly with react-router-dom]

I have used **"react-router-dom": "^5.0.1"**

How to resolve this and pass value correctly using `<Link/>` or something better.(Except *redux* - still learning)

Comment: if you pass a `value` prop to an `input` you need to provide an `onChange` handler. If you don't wish to handle change yourself, pass value using `defaultValue` prop, not `value`. The error message is quite self-explanatory, does it even requires any explanation.

Comment: this doesn't work , please see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQIdR.png) . It still gives me nothing.

Comment: there are a million errors, set up a demo on codesandbox or something

Comment: I'm new in codesandbox.io, but [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-haze-7rqgw?fontsize=14) is my setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to pass your params as path url params inside your router , So change your router component to

```
<Route path="/edit/:id/:email/:name" component={ProfileEdit} />
```

or if you want to make them not required just set your router to

```
<Route path="/edit/:id?/:email?/:name?" component={ProfileEdit} />
```

the link would be somthing like :

```
<Link to={{pathname:`/edit/${this.state.userID}/${this.state.email}/${this.state.userName}`}}>
```

then in the `ProfileEdit` component access those info by using the match props

so the values get accessed like :

```
this.state.email = this.props.match.params.email;
this.state.userName = this.props.match.params.name;
this.state.userID = this.props.match.params.id;
```

also the to remove error thrown : add onChange (controlled) to your input or replace value with defaultValue attr (uncontrolled ) see [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values) for more info .

the new input of TextField Component should look like

```
<div className="form-label-group">
       <input type="text" id="inputEmail" defaultValue={valueOfEmail} className="form-control" placeholder="Name" required autoFocus/>
       <label htmlFor="inputEmail">Enter Name</label>
</div>
```

if there are too mush params then you have to use a store manager , (too mush param in url , ugly and could lead to errors )

Comment: When I use facebook I goto https://www.facebook.com/ or https://www.facebook.com/notifications not https://www.facebook.com/**userName**

That's why I'm demotivated in this strategy.

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/maifeeulasad/6e248a8ed8159259fdc0c3feb17ea417) is my code. It's not rendering as it meant to be. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yLFO.png) is what it is rendering.

Comment: `{this.state.errorName}` instead of `{this.props.errorName}`

Comment: I'm asking for one more favor. Can you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57735934/10305444) and give me some sort of solution or suggestion regarding this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your route is like this:

```
<Route path="/edit/:id" component=componentName />
```

Try this :

```
<Link to={`/edit/${this.state.value}`} />
```

Comment: My `Route` looks like this :

`<Route path="/edit" component={ProfileEdit} />`

Comment: Your route must be like "/edit/:id" then you pass state value to link and access that state value in ProfileEdit component by : this.props.params.match.id

Comment: When I use facebook I goto `https://www.facebook.com/` or `https://www.facebook.com/notifications` not `https://www.facebook.com/**userName**`

Comment: that's facebook and facebook is not fully developed in react. if you want to pass state value in profileEdit component then you have to pass it as props like <ProfileEdit state={this.state.value} />

Comment: Talking about **https://www.facebook.com/username** then route is defined as <Route path="/:profileId" component /> and Link is like <Link to={`${this.state.profileId}`} /> and that profileId is stored in sessionStorage while user logged in, so that can be used until user logged out or widow closed. You can not set session time in react,it can be set by backend programming.

Comment: Yes, trying to do the same thing with `react-redux`. (just started learning)

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/maifeeulasad/6e248a8ed8159259fdc0c3feb17ea417) is my code. It's not rendering as it meant to be. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yLFO.png) is what it is rendering.