# react,js component rendering partially

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

[Here](https://github.com/maifeeulasad/StackOverFlow-Share/tree/react.js-partial-render-problem) is the full project, I have created a new project with minimal CSS and no CSS created by me. And the result is same.

Here is code of my `Home` class :

```
class Home extends React.Component{
state={};
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="container">

                <h1>Assignment Submission System</h1>
                <p className="lead">To get latest notification, click
                    <tab>
                        <Link to={"/notifications"}>
                            here
                        </Link>
                    </tab>
                    .
                </p>
                <p>All enrolled class-rooms, assignment to-do list are shown.</p>

                <h2 className="mt-4">Class-rooms:</h2>
                <ClassRoomUnit displayName={"class 1"} classID={"4324ax"} hLink={"/class/asd"}/>
                <ClassRoomUnit displayName={"class 2"} classID={"4324ax"} hLink={"/class/xzx"}/>
                <ClassRoomUnit displayName={"class 3"} classID={"4324ax"} hLink={"/class/asd"}/>
                <ClassRoomUnit displayName={"class 4"} classID={"4324ax"} hLink={"/class/asd"}/>
            </div>

        </div>
    );

}
}
export default Home;
```

But the problem is, when there is only very few `ClassRoomUnit` item, it renders correctly :

[image: react.js flooding and rendering problem]

But when I add a lot more `ClassRoomUnit`, first portion and many item disappears, although the scrollbar remains :

[image: react.js flooding and rendering problem]
How this can be solved ?

Comment: This is not an issue in react, rather in your css. Please check devtools. Inspect the elements if it is there in your dom.

Comment: And without the css nobody but you can answer this question.

Comment: i guess, yes : https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0c5h.png

Comment: I'm using bootstarp , this [grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/grid/) from example.

Comment: I have added all style sheet being used

Comment: Hi @MaifeeUlAsad , reproducing the example render correctly without error, seems somthing added like portion of js code , or some css style the cause the issue !
could you upload the result page as html file ?

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/maifeeulasad/d1cec0b563dd0200e069b4faac955025) is what it looks like.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/maifeeulasad/StackOverFlow-Share/tree/react.js-partial-render-problem) is the full project, I have created a new project with minimal CSS and no CSS created by me. And the result is same. Can you please look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/floating-labels/) beautiful floating label example. And directly copy pasted the used .css [file](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/floating-labels/floating-labels.css).

Maybe for these few lines :

```
html,
body {
   height: 100%;
}
```

It created all these problem, now I have moved all the rest css to another css file except this one, and my pages are rendering fully.

Till now, thanks to all those guys, who gave their valuable time on my question. It was really a headache for me, I had to change my templates. Which is really hard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

there must be some CSS, some class which is causing this for you. Can you fork my example stackblitz, make changes from your code to see if we can replicate the case here - it is much easier to help if we can all see the effects.

My **index.js** code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class ClassRoomUnit extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { displayName: this.props.displayName, classID: this.props.classID, hLink: this.props.hLink }
  }
  render() {
    return (<div class='row'>
      <div class='col-4 themed-grid-col'>  {this.state.displayName} </div>
      <div class='col-4 themed-grid-col'>  {this.state.classID} </div>
      <div class='col-4 themed-grid-col'> <a href={this.state.hLink}>Go to class room</a> </div>
    </div>)
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container">

          <h1>Assignment Submission System</h1>
          <p className="lead">To get latest notification, click here
              .
                </p>
          <p>All enrolled class-rooms, assignment to-do list are shown.</p>

          <h2 className="mt-4">Class-rooms:</h2>
          <ClassRoomUnit displayName={"class 1"} classID={"4324ax"} hLink={"/class/asd"} />
          <ClassRoomUnit displayName={"class 2"} classID={"4324ax"} hLink={"/class/xzx"} />
          <ClassRoomUnit displayName={"class 3"} classID={"4324ax"} hLink={"/class/asd"} />
          <ClassRoomUnit displayName={"class 4"} classID={"4324ax"} hLink={"/class/asd"} />

          <ClassRoomUnit displayName={"class 5"} classID={"4324ax"} hLink={"/class/asd"} />
          <ClassRoomUnit displayName={"class 6"} classID={"4324ax"} hLink={"/class/xzx"} />
          <ClassRoomUnit displayName={"class 7"} classID={"4324ax"} hLink={"/class/asd"} />
          <ClassRoomUnit displayName={"class 8"} classID={"4324ax"} hLink={"/class/asd"} />

          <ClassRoomUnit displayName={"class 9"} classID={"4324ax"} hLink={"/class/asd"} />
          <ClassRoomUnit displayName={"class 10"} classID={"4324ax"} hLink={"/class/xzx"} />
          <ClassRoomUnit displayName={"class 11"} classID={"4324ax"} hLink={"/class/asd"} />
          <ClassRoomUnit displayName={"class 12"} classID={"4324ax"} hLink={"/class/asd"} />

          <ClassRoomUnit displayName={"class 13"} classID={"4324ax"} hLink={"/class/asd"} />
          <ClassRoomUnit displayName={"class 14"} classID={"4324ax"} hLink={"/class/xzx"} />
          <ClassRoomUnit displayName={"class 15"} classID={"4324ax"} hLink={"/class/asd"} />
          <ClassRoomUnit displayName={"class 16"} classID={"4324ax"} hLink={"/class/asd"} />

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

working [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-aasxu2)

Comment: Doesn't work, can you see again please. I have updated my question.

Comment: Well now it renders correctly in my firefox browser only. I don't know what's wrong...

Comment: The inner browser of chrome, takes infinite time to render nothing(I waited for 2 hours). See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0pxi.png). If it is problem with browser, how this can be resolved ?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/maifeeulasad/StackOverFlow-Share/tree/react.js-partial-render-problem) is the full project, I have created a new project with minimal CSS and no CSS created by me. And the result is same. Can you please look.